# How to update JList dynamically from another JLIst?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have two Jlist(blockList and layerList) and I am trying to update the values of the blockList when I click on a different item from the layerList. For some reason it is not working. Here is my code:

```
  JButton openButton, saveButton;
  JTextArea log;
  JFileChooser fc;
  JList layerList;
  JList blockList;
  DefaultListModel model;
  String[] layers = {"Layer 1", "Layer 2", "Layer 3", "Layer 4", "Layer 5"};
  String[] blocksListMenu1 = {"Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", "Block 4", "Block 5"};
  String[] blocksListMenu2 = {"Block 6", "Block 7", "Block 8", "Block 9", "Block 10"};
  String[] blocksListMenu3 = {"Block 11", "Block 12", "Block 13", "Block 14", "Block 15"};
  String[] blocksListMenu4 = {"Block 16", "Block 17", "Block 18", "Block 19", "Block 20"};
  String[] blocksListMenu5 = {"Block 21", "Block 22", "Block 23", "Block 24", "Block 25"};

public MainPage() {
super(new BorderLayout());  

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

final JPanel layerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
layerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
layerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

JLabel layerLabel = new JLabel("Layers:");
layerList = new JList(layers);
layerList.setSelectedIndex(0);
layerList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
     @Override
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        blockList = new JList();
        String selectedLayer = layers[layerList.getSelectedIndex()];
        if(selectedLayer.equals("Layer 1"))
             blockList.setListData(blocksListMenu1);
        else if(selectedLayer.equals("Layer 2"))
             blockList.setListData(blocksListMenu2);
        else if(selectedLayer.equals("Layer 3"))
             blockList.setListData(blocksListMenu3);
        else if(selectedLayer.equals("Layer 4"))
             blockList.setListData(blocksListMenu4);
        else if(selectedLayer.equals("Layer 5"))
             blockList.setListData(blocksListMenu5);;
    }
});

layerPanel.add(layerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
layerPanel.add(layerList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
layerPanel.setVisible(false);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

final JPanel blockPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
blockPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
blockPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

JLabel blockLabel = new JLabel("Blcoks:");
blockList = new JList(blocksListMenu1);
blockPanel.add(blockLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
blockPanel.add(blockList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
blockPanel.setVisible(false);

final JTextField path = new JTextField();
JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("DXF Files", "dxf");
      fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
      int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
        path.setText(selectedFile.getPath());
        layerPanel.setVisible(true);
        blockPanel.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
});    

content.add(path, BorderLayout.CENTER);
content.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(7, 7, 7, 7));
add(content, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(layerPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
add(blockPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

}

When I choose the file the selected index of layersList is 0 which means that the selected item is "Layer 1" and the blockList is showing the correct array. But when I press item "Layer 2" it is not updating.

Any ideas why ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new `JList`, and setting the data of that:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    blockList = new JList();
    ...
```

The new list has not been added to the container, so it won't be visible anywhere.
You should simply change the data of the already existing `JList` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I feel kind of stupid now because it was obvious :) Thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: @chikito1990 You're welcome. Obvious bugs are sometimes hard to find, because as the authors we are blind to them.

Answer (score 1):

@chikito1990: Reason is you are instantiating `blockList` in `valueChanged()` that is why every time it is re instantiating while you should have one instantiate and for that you should instantiate `blockList` in the constructor.

```
public MainPage() {
...

blockList = new JList();

...

}
```

try this, it will work.